# How to implement At most once delivery consumer semantic using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I went through the below two links :

- https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-clients-at-most-once-at-least-once-exactly-o
- https://medium.com/@andy.bryant/processing-guarantees-in-kafka-12dd2e30be0e

They both have two different approach to achieve At Most Once consumer semantics, so I am a little confuse
which one to follow.

#### My current consumer configuration is :

```
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=true
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=<server port>
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

#### Below is my consumer code base :

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = TOPIC, groupId = consumerGroupId)
    public void streamListener(@Payload String message,
                               @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) long producerTimestamp) {

        parseMessage(message, producerTimestamp);

    }
}
```

What my `parseMessage()` does, is that it process the messages and save it to the NOSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that both articles mention a slightly different configuration to achieve At Most Once semantics on the consumer side. However, they are in fact equal in their approaches.

The idea of At Most Once semantics can be summarised as

> For “at most once” delivery, commit messages immediately after `poll()` and then process the messages.

Now, this can be achieved in two ways, either with using the automated commit or by ensuring that you call `commitSync()` right after your `poll()` call and before further processing of the data.

#### Option 1 (as described in first article)

- Set `enable.auto.commit` to true.
- Set `auto.commit.interval.ms` to a lower timeframe. (Remark: This should be set to the minimum value)
- And do not make call to `consumer.commitSync()`; from the consumer.

With this configuration of consumer, Kafka would auto commit offset at the specified interval.

#### Option 2 (as described in second article)

- The consumer application has `enable.auto.commit` set to false
- and is programmed to commit their offsets back to Kafka **prior to writing to the database**.

You see, both articles share the same general idea and as usual there are multiple ways to implement this.

Comment: but my consumer is reprocessing the messages, I guess offset is not getting auto committed even after setting the `enable-auto-commit` to `true` in my properties file, I just updated my question with my consumer implementation code please feel free to guide me.

Comment: how is your `consumerGroupId` defined?